# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Anime & Manga's [fourth moderator election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Aki Tanaka]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6213498292928512/0).

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations Aki! I wish you all the luck in your new position and may you serve the community well :)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, thank you to all who have participated in this election, as candidates and also as voters. :)

I'd like to thank [Wondercricket](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/20275) for stepping up as a strong candidate, hopefully you will get a chance in future elections!

Also, I'd like to thank [Fumikage Tokoyami](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/48011) for caring about the election and stepping up as a candidate to ensure the election went through. It was my bad to gamble on extending the nomination period... :(

Finally, I hope for good teamwork with the community and guidance from the existing mod team!